# Why use return in jquery if code works perfectly fine without it?

Tags: jquery, function, return

I'm a jQuery newbie. Here are two code snippets that move the h1 element below the first paragraph. They do precisely the same thing.

```
$('p').eq(0).after(function() {
return $(this).prev();
});
```

and

```
$('p').eq(0).after( $('h1') );
```

Which code practice is preferable? Why?

Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT:

Here's the html.

```
<article>
<h1>Post</h1>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</p>
<p>
    <span class=co>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
</p>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</p>
</article>
```

Comment: Wheres the html, hard to tell because at first glance they seem to do different things...

Comment: I guess your html is something like this : <h1>title</h1> <p>lorem ipsum</p> the first code query the element before `p`, in this precise case : `h1` while the second code query each `h1` element from the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The first code**: select all `p` elements, get the first found and put after it a element returned on the callback. `this` on callback is referent to the selected `p`. So the `console.log` return the `p` element. The `return` return the element before the selected `p`. On this case, the selected `p` is the first `Lorem ipsum`. And the previous element is the `h1`. Then the `h1` is returned and attached `after()` the `p` element.

**The second code**: will work similar, for this specific case. But watch out! On this case you will get all `p` elements and filter it, getting the first one (like first code) so you will attach `after` it all found `h1` elements. How in your example HTML code you have only one `h1` element, it not will be a problem. But if you have two or more, you will have trouble!

Comment: I suppose if I were to use the second code snippet and include more h1 elements, I'd have to specify which h1 I mean by including a class or id. Any reason not to do it this way?

Comment: Yeah. The first code is better for what you want currently. If get the previous `h1` and put it after the `p` element. You can try it too (just for fun): http://jsfiddle.net/XzP7J/ so all `h1` will be attached after the next `p` element.

Comment: The only reason the first code is better is because of the way the html is structured in this particular example, with the h1 preceding the first p - correct?  As joakimdahlstrom points out in another answer below, something like ('p').eq(0).after( $('h1.class') ) would result in greater flexibility with the html so might be a better long term strategy.

Comment: The `h1` need stay before the `p` element to the first code works. If you need take a specific `h1` element and put it `after()` a specific `p` element, you need do something like that: `$('p.item1').after($('h1.item1'))`.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the second alternative, because it's smarter, shorter and looks better.

The..

```
$('p').eq(0).after(function() {
    return $(this).prev(); 
});
```

..would mean that the structure of the existing html has to stay the way it is. If you do it the second way, you can add things between the first paragraph and the `h1`, and it would still work.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I'm not sure I understand why the html structure would have to remain the same with the first example in particular. In the case of either code snippet, if I added more 'p' elements the functionality of the jquery would be the same. It would simply find the first 'p' element and then place the 'h1' below that. Am I missing something?

Comment: As long as you always have h1's followed by p's you're fine. But it will grab the previous element, regardless of its type. If you have anything between the first p and the h1, then that element will be moved to the wanted position. In your second example you say "the h1 will be placed after the first paragraph", and it will always work that way no matter what elements you have in between.